# why does my microwave beep half way through a defrost?

Tags: microwave, defrosting

When I defrost meat in my microwave, it will beep about half way through the cycle. I'm assuming this is to indicate to me that I need to do something, I'm just not sure what.

- Am I supposed to check to see the progress?
- Am I to remove the meat and re-evaluate?
- Are there health concerns associated with ignoring the beep?

Comment: Did you read your manual?

Comment: The microwave came built in (over the range) with the house. No manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's reminding you that flipping meat halfway through the defrost cycle will help prevent the bottom half cooking, while the top remains frozen solid.

Comment: Mine actually displays "turn over" where the clock belongs while it's beeping. And it makes a huge difference. When I turn it over, I get perfectly defrosted meat. When I don't, it's uneven - still frozen in places and starting to cook in others.